# 40Gbps Thunderbolt 4 (TB4) connection between Mac and Linux

Tags: network, thunderbolt, data-transfer

I want to connect a M1 Max Macbook Pro  16"  64gb ram (2021) with a GIGABYTE GA-Z170X-Gaming 5 Core i5 Intel +  GIGABYTE GC-MAPLE RIDGE, PCIe 3.0 x4 card (Intel JHL8540 (Maple Ridge)). What is the maximum connection speed I can achieve?

I could not find any success reports online (except a [weird video report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krNyms2uGdg)). Did anyone ever successfully achieve 40Gbps connection?

Comment: Maximum throughputs are always theoretical numbers so you'll never see "40Gb/s" throughput.  You asked about a very specific set of hardware so it's very unlikely you'll get feedback specific to this setup.  That said, what's the ultimate goal here?  If it doesn't meet some throughput benchmark are you going to go a different route?  Is there a real-world, practical problem to be solved here?

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a problem. I need to connect to another computer from my Apple (a machine running a hardware raid). I need to store realtime captured video streams (4x 4K uncompressed). As for PCs the only TB4 controller is the Intel Maple Ridge, the setup is not specific, but should be the same for all the PCs with TB4 addon cards. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: (Not trying to be pedantic).  I'm not seeing the issue.  Your options are limited with what you can connect and a direct TB connection seems to be the highest performing option.  You could get several 10G Ethernet adapters and aggregate them, but in the end, you'll still only have the 40G in (theoretical) throughput.  So, whether or not you see the full 40Gbps, what are you other options here (that also keep it on topic for this site)?